# How do i create name of List dynamically?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I am trying to create =>

```
{
  "Data1":{
     "DataListOne": [0, 1],
     "DataListTwo": [1, 0, 0, 0]
          },
  "Data2":{
     "DataListOne": [1, 0],
     "DataListTwo": [0, 0, 0, 1]
          },
  "Data-n" : { 
     "DataListOne": [1, 0],
     "DataListTwo": [0, 1, 0, 0]
          } 
}
```

List dynamically that starting from Data1 to Data-n that is not specified at which point i need to stop that List and also want Two List (DataListOne, DataListTwo) inside Data1 to Data-n.

I am not getting how to create List Dynamically from Data1 to Data-n and also the Two List (DataListOne, DataListTwo) inside Dynamic List from Data1 to Data-n

Please Help Me With This.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use [Json.NET](http://json.net) for this - it lets you build up the JSON dynamically:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var pairs = new List<ListPair>
        {
            new ListPair
            {
                DataListOne = { 0, 1 },
                DataListTwo = { 1, 0, 0, 0 }
            },
            new ListPair
            {
                DataListOne = { 1, 0 },
                DataListTwo = { 0, 0, 0, 1 }
            },
            new ListPair
            {
                DataListOne = { 1, 0 },
                DataListTwo = { 0, 1, 0, 0 }
            },
        };

        JObject json = CreateJson(pairs);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }

    static JObject CreateJson(List<ListPair> pairs)
    {
        return new JObject(pairs.Select(
           (pair, index) => new JProperty("Data" + (index + 1),
                                          JObject.FromObject(pair))));

    }

    class ListPair
    {
        public List<int> DataListOne, DataListTwo;

        public ListPair()            
        {
            DataListOne = new List<int>();
            DataListTwo = new List<int>();
        }
    }
}
```

On the other hand, I think it would be cleaner to just create an array in the JSON rather than having the names generated dynamically.

Comment: answered by the god of codding Jon Skeet himself...what else u want OP :D